# split - ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a text file which has data in this format:

```
column : row
```

This is some sample data:

```
Name of the Property : North Kensington Upcycling Store and Cafe
Availability : Now 
Interest Level : 74 people are looking right now
Area :  1,200 sqft
Retail Type  : No
Bar & Restaurant Type  : No
```

My code gives this error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

at this line:

```
    k,v = txt_line.split(":")
```

My code:

```
import pandas
txt_file = r"patty.txt"
txt = open(txt_file, "r")
txt_string = txt.read()
txt_lines = txt_string.split("\n")
txt_dict = {}

for txt_line in txt_lines:
    print(txt_line)
    k,v = txt_line.split(":")
    k = k.strip()
    v = v.strip()
    if k in txt_dict:
        list = txt_dict.get(k)
    else:
        list = []
    list.append(v)
    txt_dict[k]=list
print (pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(txt_dict, orient="index"))
```

Comment: I tried to run it with minimum data say only the first 3 lines and I still get the error..am i doing anything wrong with the logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a line of the input file is empty or missing the colon, `split` returns only 1 element and you get that error.

To play it safe, I would do a size check to avoid the exception, and print an explicit message when parsing is not possible (I added empty line skip to avoid crashing in that case)

```
if txt_line.strip():
   # line is not empty or just blanks
   toks = txt_line.split(":")
   if len(toks)==2:
       # unpack safely
       k,v = toks
   else:
       print("unable to parse {}".format(txt_line))
```

Comment: Fabre , No actually it was a mistake when i tried to copy and paste the data here. I dont think thats the problem.

Comment: Can you change your code by mine and see what happens? must be something else like empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: ya one min please !

Comment: It says unable to parse @Jean-François Fabre

Comment: it's an empty line as predicted. I edited my code to skip them.